# MEF not loading Imports

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mef

I have a main app that will have many plugins. Here is the `PluginReader` class in my main app:

```
Public Class PluginReader
 <ImportMany(GetType(IWebPlugin))>
    Private m_WebPlugins As IEnumerable(Of Lazy(Of IWebPlugin))

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Property WebPlugins As IEnumerable(Of Lazy(Of IWebPlugin))
        Get
            Return m_WebPlugins
        End Get
        Set(value As IEnumerable(Of Lazy(Of IWebPlugin)))
            m_WebPlugins = value
        End Set
    End Property   
End Class
```

In my plugin I have this code:

```
<Export(GetType(IWebPlugin))>
<PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)>
Public Class PluginClass
    Implements IWebPlugin
    'Code to implement IWebPlugin here
```

My custom controller factor reads my plugin's exports correctly and I can see that the IWebPlugin is exported, but the ImportMany is not being populated.

**If you need any clarification please let me know! Thanks!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add a compose method to the `PluginReader` class.

```
 Private Sub Compose()

        Dim catalog As AggregateCatalog = New AggregateCatalog()
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(New DirectoryCatalog(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "bin"))
        Dim container As New CompositionContainer(catalog)
        container.ComposeParts(Me)

    End Sub
```

This was my constructor:

```
Public Sub New()
        Compose()
    End Sub
```